# Numerical plot problem

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

[image]Im simulating numericlly Rayleigh-Plesset eq. (second order, inhomogeneous).
There is a problem like that.
I solve this eqaution on section [0,80*10^-6]
I plot temperature (function of solution) wchich on the same interval.
Then I plot temperature on the smaller section [0,28*10^-6] and get completly diffrent solution.
There are not specific sections. 
The problem is of course that when i change section Wolfram changes solutions.
I tried to change methods to methodlines, stiffnes switching. Tried to change accuracies but nothing.
Probably im doing it wrong because its not working.
Thank you for attetion.
That's my first post. I just started with numerics

```
Pa = (1.8)*10^5;
P0 = 1*10^5 ;
rhoi = 10^(-3); 
omega = 2*30000*3.14;
c = 1500;
S = 74.9*10^-3; 
R0 = 25*10^-6;
R = 8.3144598;
na = 6.02214076*10^23;
u = nt/na
pi = 3.1315213721372137
mikro = 1.52*10^(-3);
gamma = 5/3;
Ti = 280;
nO = 1*10^12;
nH = 1*10^12;
nAr = 10^10;
nt = nO + nAr + 2*nH;
a = a11*x1^2 + 2*a12*x1*x2 + a22*x2^2;
b = b11*x1^2 + 2*b12*x1*x2 + b22*x2^2;
a12 = Sqrt[a11*a22];
b12 = ((1/2) (CubeRoot[b11] + CubeRoot[ b22]))^3;`

`(*HERE IS THE FUNCTION I PLOT. T2*)
T2[t] = Ti*(((R0)^3 - ((3*u*b)/(4*pi)))/((y[t])^3 - ((3*u*b)/(4*pi))))^((gamma - 1));
T[t] = Ti*(R0/y[t])^(3*(gamma - 1));
(*ANOTHER LIST OF PARAMETERS AND FUNCTIONS I USE*)
g1 = 2.8;
(*argon*)
h = (R0)/(8.86); (*to pochodzi od r0 r0*)
(*bohr radius dla argonu*)
abr = 0.71*10^(-10);
MAr = 32.5*1.66*10^(-27);
a11 = 1.355;
b11 = 0.03201*10^-3;
x1 = nAr/nt;
(*H20*)
MH2O = (18.015*10^(-3))/(6.23*10^23);
a22 = 5.536; (*to jest w litrach*)
b22 = 0.05105*10^-3;
x2 = (2*nH + nO)/nt;
rhol[t] = rho ((pl[t] + B)/(P0 + B))^(1/n)
rho = 1000;
n = 6.015;
B = 3638.17*10^5; 
cl[t] = Sqrt[(n (pl[t] + B))/(rhol[t])];
pl[t] = (Pa)*Cos[(omega)*(t + (y[t])/(c))] - P0 + pc[t] - 
   4 mikro *(y'[t]/y[t]) - 2*(S/y[t]);
pc[t] = (P0 + (2*S)/
     R0) (((R0)^3 - ((3*u*b)/(4*pi)))/(y[t]^3 - ((3*u*b)/(4*pi))))^
   gamma;(*ubogie ciśnienie dla ogólnego gazu*)
Vm[t] = nt/(na*V[t]); (*tak zwana gęstość molowa*)
pf[t] = D[pc[t], t]
kb = 1.38064852*10^(-23);(*Boltzman*)
(*This is a function i use in T2*)
V[t] = 4/3*3.14152137 (y[t])^3; 
(*MY ND SOLVE*)
i = 80*10^-6;
ode1 = {(1 - (y'[t])/cl[t]) (y[t] y''[t]) + (3/2 ) (1 - (y'[t]/(3 cl[t]))) (y'[t])^2 == (1 + (y'[t])/cl[t]) (1/rhol[t])*((Pa)*Sin[(omega)*(t + (y[t])/(cl[t]))] + pc[t] - P0 - 4 mikro *(y'[t]/y[t]) - 
       2*(S/y[t])) + (y[t]/(cl[t]*rhol[t])) pf[t], y[0] == R0, y'[0] == 10^(-5)}
sol = NDSolve[ode1, y, {t, 0, i}]  
(*PLOTS*)
Plot[T2[t] /. sol, {t, 0*10^-5, i}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
Plot[T2[t] /. sol, {t, 0*10^-6, 28*10^-6}, PlotRange -> {0, 20000}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Thank You again

Comment: Use `{Plot[T2[t] /. sol, {t, 0*10^-5, i}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotPoints -> 800],
 Plot[T2[t] /. sol, {t, 0*10^-6, 28*10^-6}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotPoints -> 400]}`

Comment: Im sorry, but what with precison of that?  How good it is?

Comment: But its great that it generates two the same things!

Comment: Ok! Is it solve your problem?

Comment: Probably yes. Very important here is accuracy of my calculations. I belive that if I add more plotpoints the plot will be more accurate?

Comment: It is nothing do with accuracy of numerical solution, but only with `Plot` functionality. If you like to see residuals of the numerical solution then use this code `residuals = ode1 /. Equal -> Subtract; {s} = NDSolve[ode1, y, {t, 0, i}, InterpolationOrder -> All]; ListPlot[Abs[(residuals /. t -> y["Coordinates"] /. s)] // First,  Frame -> True]`

Comment: Thank You very much!

Comment: You are welcome! By the way, what version are you running? Check `$Version`.

Comment: My version is 12.0

Comment: Could you post pictures what you getting from `Plot`?

Comment: I post what i got from plot after your update, and the residuals.

Comment: That was what you want?

Comment: Ok! Thank you. Is `pi` in your code just $\pi$?

Comment: Yes. I aware that it have not good digits. I put it that way for a joke, and forgot to change it.

Comment: But with `pi=Pi//N` it looks better.

Comment: ok, then, thank You very much!